# Extensiong ambiguous error

Tags: c#

I have next class:

```
public static class Monads
{
    public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
        where TInput: class
        where TResult: class
    {
        if (o == null) return null;
        return evaluator(o);
    }

    public static Nullable<TResult> With<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
        where TInput : class
        where TResult : struct
    {
        if (o == null) return null;
        return evaluator(o);
    }
}
```

When i try to use it i got a error:
"Error  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `'CoreLib.Monads.With<TInput,TResult>(TInput, System.Func<TInput,TResult>)'` and `'CoreLib.Monads.With<TInput,TResult>(TInput, System.Func<TInput,TResult>)'`"

But this methods a different by type's constrains and Nullable is struct.
However, this code works fine:

```
public static class Monads
{
    public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator,
        TResult failureValue)
        where TInput: class
    {
        if (o == null) return failureValue;
        return evaluator(o);
    }


    public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>
        (this Nullable<TInput> o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator,
        TResult failureValue)
        where TInput : struct
    {
        if (!o.HasValue) return failureValue;

        return evaluator(o.Value);
    }
}
```

What a reason of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to overload methods, either the parameters must be different types or else there must be a different number of parameters. In your example:

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>
    (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)         

public static Nullable<TResult> With<TInput, TResult>
    (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
```

You can see that the parameters are exactly the same. Your second example works because you are writing an extension method to two different kinds of objects, `this Nullable<TInput> o` and `this TInput o`

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you have the same parameter types (this TInput o, Func evaluator).